# Jquery implementation problems on batch image load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have problems with regards on 2 JQuery libraries and im trying to implement a batch image load plugin. but i am getting some jquery conflict. some of my functions doesnt work when i put the new one.

this is my default one:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

the batchimageload plugin uses

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.yankov.us/batchImageLoad/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

The batchimageload works if i will use the second one but some i lose some functions on my webpage for i dont know what reason.

Comment: jquery.min.js" are same in both case  i think there is issue regarding version

Comment: the plugin seems to be using jquery 1.3.2.. try including the migration plugin and see whether it works

Comment: which one should i replace with the migration plugin?

Comment: @CarloBrew, the bottom one

Comment: You can also use both versions of jquery. look at this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331193/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page. you have to change some codes though.