# jQuery noconflict() with external resource

Tags: jquery

I'm loading an external JavaScript source (link: [FirstGiving](http://developers.firstgiving.com/documentation/nonprofit-search-plugin/)) which utilizes jQuery 1.6.2, but the rest of my page uses jQuery 1.10.2 (and I don't want to switch to an older version for just this page).

The 1.6.2 widget looks up non-profit organizations from a database and presents them to the user. I want to simply use the widget, but keep the rest of my page working with jQuery 1.10.2

HTML:

```
<div id="fgGraphWidgetContainer"></div><br />

Name: <span id="fg_charity_name"></span><br />
UUID: <span id="fg_uuid"></span><br />
EIN: <span id="fg_ein"></span>
```

JS:

```
var FG_GRAPHWIDGET_PARAMS = {
results : {
selectaction : function(uuid, charity_name, ein) {
    document.getElementById("fg_charity_name").innerHTML=charity_name;
    document.getElementById("fg_uuid").innerHTML=uuid;
    document.getElementById("fg_ein").innerHTML=ein;
}
}
};
```

I can get it to work when I select jQuery v1.8.3 in the Fiddle, but not with a newer version of jQuery (like on my site). - also, I've tried desperately with `noConflict()`, but that doesn't seem to get both working at the same time either.

http://jsfiddle.net/bPQ5r/2/

Comment: Try with jQuery Migrate plugin.

Comment: `jQuery.noConflict` just disowns the `$` variable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21736074/3300831

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331193/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page

http://forum.jquery.com/topic/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page