# How to place older jQuery version first in Wordpress?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

One of my scripts in my Wordpress theme needs an older jQuery Version (1.11.0). All other scripts run on the actual version. My idea was to load the old version at the beginning and using `$111 = jQuery.noConflict();` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13331193/multiple-versions-of-jquery-on-the-same-page). After that the actual jQuery version should be loaded.

Can I place it before the actual version and assign it to e.g. `$111` by using `wp_enqueue_script`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a good idea to load second jQuery library. If some of the plugins needs older version of jQuery, try to add [jQuery Migrate](https://blog.jquery.com/2016/01/13/jquery-migrate-1-3-0-released/) and see if the old code works.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't even with jQuery migrate.

Comment: Тhe best choice is to use only one version of jQuery. If you want you can remove the default jQuery from wordpress and add older version. You can check more here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/152559/wordpress-script-loading-unloading-wp-deregister-scriptjquery. Also you can check how to enqueue the proper way libraries to wordpress

Comment: And one more thing, jQuery Migrate should be right after jQuery library, you can try that, if you have not already.

Comment: I tried to use an older version of jQuery, but the `live()` function isn't available and my theme doesn't work then correctly.

Comment: jQuery Migrate will fix the problem with live() method if it's depricated in your jQuery version

Comment: Thanks a lot, that worked! When I deregistered jquery in the my script, also jquery-migrate was removed. After I registered it again, it works now.